# How to return different mock based on different params?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an api call with param:

```
 public getPersonName(id: number): Observable<Person> {
    let searchParams: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    searchParams.append("id", id.toString());
    // my http call is down here ...
  }
```

and my mock looks like this:

```
    public handleRequest(connection: MockConnection): void {

    let request: Request = connection.request;

    // Used in Expedite
   if (request.method === RequestMethod.Get && new RegExp('\/person').test(request.url)) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(
          new ResponseOptions({
            status: 200,
            headers: new Headers(MY_HEADERS),
            body: {
              "fname": "John",
              "lname": "Deer",
              "age": 25
            }
          })
        ));
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
```

but what I want is actually to return a different json according to the id...so if id is 5325 I want to return one json result, and if id is 4545 I want to return a different json...

How do I do this?

thanks@!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `handleRequest` function is being passed to `mockBackend.connections.subscribe()`.

In this case, you can use the power of RxJS to help you here.
You can filter the connections emitted and reply to them differently.

As a bonus, you not even need to use `setTimeout`, since RxJS also provides you with a delay operator.

```
mockBackend.connections
  .filter(({ request }) => request.method === RequestMethod.Get && request.url === '/person/123')
  .delay(1000)
  .subscribe(conn => {
    // Respond for person 123
    conn.mockRespond({});
  });

mockBackend.connections
  .filter(({ request }) => request.method === RequestMethod.Get && request.url === '/person/456')
  .delay(1000)
  .subscribe(conn => {
    // Respond for person 456
    conn.mockRespond({});
  });
```

Comment: thanks allot for the great answer, is theres a chance you can give me a solution that will keep the current structure of the mock?

Comment: You can just build it however you like (eg pass your `handleRequest` method). I just pointed out what could help you solve your challenge, instead of using ugly `if`s in your tests :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution to the current structure:

```
if (request.method === RequestMethod.Get && new RegExp('\/person').test(request.url) && req.url.endsWith('123'))
```